# Yet another ecs-cli and Parameter Store question

Tags: amazon-ec2, docker-compose, amazon-ecs, aws-cli, aws-parameter-store

Hoping I'll catch a break as a complete ECS **NOOB** =)

So far I *think* I've managed to build out a good start, using ECS-CLI to create a cluster for two docker containers that go together and should run on the same instance (x2). However, at the time of either my `ecs-cli up` or my `ecs-cli compose`, I need to get the command to build the task in such a way that it can access a set of environment variables stored in AWS Parameter Store. I don't see any options to do that with ecs-cli, for neither 'up' nor 'compose'.

What am I missing? Help! I'm not sure yet what other info to provide, or I'd post all that I can, so please let me know what other data/background you need if you think you have an answer.

All comments very much appreciated of course!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the `secrets` section in the `ecs-cli` documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cmd-ecs-cli-compose-ecsparams.html). You would configure ECS to pull those secrets from SSM Parameter Store and inject them as environment variables into your container using that method.

Comment: Yep! Looks like, in all my experiences on this little journey, I somehow completely missed that there's an entire other file to configure, ecs-params.yml. Thank you for getting me going in the right direction.